# "Header Search Paths" vs. "User Header Search Paths" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

What's the difference? When would you use either?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Use the *User Header Search Paths* for paths you want searched for `#include "..."` and use the *Header Search Paths* for `#include <...>`.  Of course, if you check the option to *Always Search User Paths*, then `#include <...>` will also work for the user paths.

Comment: thanks! Yeah i kind of figured that, but why would you use one or the other? To me, <> should be system includes only, and everything else should be in "", but that's just my training from programming in C.
I guess <> could point to well-known libraries which are not system includes?

Comment: Yes, I think "well-known libraries" is about right.  Personally I use < > for Boost headers as well as system headers.

Comment: did not know about Boost (http://www.boost.org/)! Thanks, it looks very interesting.

Comment: `< >` is for frameworks -- `.a` and `.frameworks` "libraries" -- and it doesn't matter if it's a system framework, one of your own or a 3rd party (like Boost.)  `" "` is for project headers -- .h files that are part of the set of files being compiled.  Hope that helps clarify.