# Xcode 4 no code completion

Tags: autocomplete, xcode4

I have been using Xcode 4 for 2 weeks and I noticed that I don't get code completion macros for if-else and switch statements.

Like this article describes: http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-code-completion-macros.html

I had it working in the beginning, but it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Irina, why not accept Joshua's answer.  It will give you and Joshua rep. points, and mark the answer as closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 code sense is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431501/xcode-4-code-sense-is-not-working)

Answer (score 47):

Have you tried deleting the project's derived data (which contains the project index used by Code Sense)?

To do so, open the organizer (Window -> Organizer), then the Projects tab. Select your project then hit the delete button next to the derived data path (to the right). Confirm and let it re-index your project.

Comment: Xcode 4 definitely had some buggy indexing issues. I just upgraded from 4.0.3 to the current version of Xcode (4.2 as of this writing), and my autocomplete problems went away.

Comment: First thing Xcode 4.2 did when I opened a project was re-index the whole thing. (((hopes)))

Comment: @Andrew: Why would you *remove* helpful information (the menu path to get to the organizer) from my post? Your edits should be helpful, not less informative.

Comment: Josh, I didn't?  I was the one who added the menu path to the organizer.  I thought I was __adding__ helpful info.  I certainly didn't delete anything.

Comment: In fact, your rollback to the original did the exact opposite of what your comment said.  you rolled back to a state with __less__ information.

Comment: Ack! What the hell?! I apologize profusely - I'm not sure how I misread the edits on this old post. I just rolled back the rollback.