# Xcode completions, spelling checkings stopped

Tags: xcode

My Xcode 4.3.2 stopped to show up spelling errors and completions for code. The only way to find out if there is any error in the code - build it. Xcode colores only keywords such as `if, else, for` etc. All other code hasn't colored. Shown only a few very strange completions. For example:

```
CGPoint p;
p.y // completion is "YES"
p.x // completion is "xor"
```

Completions for methods calls are only nearaly used methods. **How can I fix this?** I rebooted my mac several times already, and didn't find any stuff about this in Xcode's preferences.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431501/xcode-4-code-sense-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do to solve this issue is:

1.) Change build settings from LLVM 3.1 to GCC 4.2

[image]
  2.) Go to Organizer>Projects>(Select Project)> Delete `Derived Data`

3.) Change Builds Settings back to LLVM 3.1

[image]

My syntax highlighting then works again. No need to restart Xcode, and jump through other hoops and hurdles.

Hope this helps you as it does for me !

**UPDATE**: Some people can get it working with only Step 2, if that doesn't work. Follow all 3 steps.

Comment: Great, I guess it works in different ways for different scenarios. Doesn't work for me only by deleting `Derived Data`

Answer (score 1):

I also had this a lot of times, what helped for me was to set in the build settings `precompile prefix header` to NO