# Xcode 4.3.3 indentation broken

Tags: xcode, indentation

Automatic indentation in my Xcode sometimes comes out wrong.  I can't see any rhyme or reason to when it is correct and when it isn't.  Here is a typical case where Xcode got it wrong.  Selecting and asking Xcode to re-indent does not help.  Of course I can fix it manually.  But it would be much better to fix whatever is wrong with my Xcode.

Any successful experiences out there?

```
-(UIFont*) font {
    UIFont* actual = self.actualFont;
    if (actual) {
        return actual;
    }
WJStyleSheet* sheet = self.styleSheet;
UIFont* r = sheet.font;
return r;
}
```

Comment: Pasting that code into XCode 4.3 indented fine here. Messing with the indentation manually and then selecting the code + pressing Control-I reformatted it correctly. So.... no idea.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with 4.5.2, but it doesn't happen all the time.  It is infrequent and hard to reproduce on command, but annoying.

Comment: This is so annoying, happens to me two to three times a week with XCode 4.6.2 (am working with C++ classes mixed in with Objective-C). Usually starts happening after I close an if statement's code block. Then everything after that if statement is broken. Naturally, it only happens now and then though!

Comment: Do you have syntax errors (IE, closing braces with no open or opens with no close?) before or after this? I find the auto indent can get funked up if braces are mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Does code completion still work completely. Can you for example type self.actual and then hit `CTRL + SPACE` and get a **coloured** code completion suggestion with the class next to `actualFont`? If not then I think this is related to the code completion which can get corrupted in Xcode.

I could fix this using the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165886/784318

Comment: Interesting idea . . . this morning it is formatting the above correctly, and the code completion is there.