# After update to Xcode 4.4 no auto completion for imports directives

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, import, header

After updating to Xcode 4.4 last week i do not get autocomplete suggestions for any of the imports.This is weird because everything else seems to be ok but it is hard to look for the name of the header file to be imported from project explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.4 Lost completion in #import "myFile.h"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687705/xcode-4-4-lost-completion-in-import-myfile-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by adding your subfolders to the "User Header Search Paths" in Targets's "Build Settings" tab (make sure to turn on the checkbox to the left).

Or, you can simply add your top folder where your .xcodeproj is located, f.e. "../trunk", or whatever name it has.

Comment: I can confirm this is a good working solution on Xcode 4.4.1. Just tried it with and without. Don't forget the checkbox on the left like he says, or it won't recurse into the subfolders.

Comment: Not a solution for my install of Xcode 4.6. It was working one minute then failed the next. Everything that can be reset has been at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Open organizer, choose your project under the Projects tab, delete derived data. Let Xcode reindex your project before doing anything else. Fixed it for me.

Comment: This solution is good for fixing code sense in just about every other scenario apart from fixing this imports problem. See @Vahrams answer for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that XCode refused to see the .h files that were imported in .pch file. Opening the build settings and setting "Precompile Prefix Header" to "No" solved my problem.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035492/936957