# Xcode indicates undeclared identifier errors for deleted variables that don't exist for C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

I restarted Xcode and loaded a C++ project I had been working on. However, I got errors for undeclared identifiers. However, these errors are for variables that are either not on the line or simply don't exist (old deleted ones).

Example:

[image]

Commenting doesn't get rid of them either:
[image]

I have tried:

1. Pulling from my repo (not sure if that replaces the file)
2. Commenting and uncommenting.
3. Reinstalling xcode.

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be great!

---

Edit: 
Someone flagged this a potential duplicate. However the questioned they referenced does not mirror my issues. I am using xcode 5 and that user, even if their problem is the same, as mine is using xcode 4 and it sounds like their issue was with porting a project created with different versions of xcode.

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431501/xcode-4-code-sense-is-not-working

Comment: Does your code compile? Are these errors purely with XCode itself?

Comment: Well I have references to functions that aren't defined yet so I know it wont compile. I don't the xcode will let it compile now though because it thinks there are these errors.

Comment: This is not a duplicate I have it tagged as xcode 5 that user even if their problem is the same as mine is using xcode 4 and it sounds like their issue was with porting a project created with different versions of xcode. Not the same thing.

Comment: Although different versions, I considered that your issue appears to be with the code sense feature and as a result the solution in that question may or may not work for you.

Comment: Just because you are using a different version of the software does not mean you should outright ignore any potential solution. Especially given that the solution I referenced appears to solve a problem similar to your own.

Comment: @ctor Either the restart or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663353/2848483 worked. Good point ctor and thanks for the help. I think to me if the question is different and the answer is the same the question itself is not a "duplicate" but I'm new here so...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either a restart or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9663353/2848483 worked thanks to ctor for finding that question.