# Adding libxml2 in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, libxml2, ios-frameworks

I have added libxml2 to my Xcode 4 project following [this guide](http://cmar.me/2011/04/20/adding-libxml2-to-an-xcode-4-project/).

But it's not working. Xcode gives me error saying it no such libxml2 directory. What am I doing wrong? Here's the screenshots of the target settings of my project:
[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

1. add ${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2 to "Header Search Paths" instead of "User Header Search Paths" under yourtarget -> Build Settings -> Search Paths
2. link with libxml2.dylib in yourtarget -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
3. include libxml2 headers with, for instance, `#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>` and you're off

for better explanation see to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429301/149663

Answer (score 27):

## Adding libxml2.2.dylib For Xcode 7, Xcode 8.0, Xcode 8.1,

Do the following steps,

1. Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies.
2. Press "Other" button.
3. After file selection appeared, Press "CMD"+"Shift"+"G"
4. Type "/usr/lib/"
5. Select "libxml2.2.dylib"

Thats all.

Comment: It really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `Always Search User Paths` to YES also.
That with "${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2" on your `User header search paths` should work.

Answer (score 2):

In "Other flags" add -lxml2 And also change the Header to ${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2

Answer (score 1):

${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2