# Can I use sqlite to query an XML file?

Tags: xml, sqlite

### Can I use sqlite to query an XML file?

I want to implement a simple c++ application that can query XML files, is it possible using sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. You would have to import the XML data into a sqlite database and query the database. Depending on the structure of your XML, that may or may not work well. [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) might be a better solution for you.

Comment: What C++ Libraries/Implementations you know of do you suggest for both scenarios "Xpath" and "Importing"? I would be looking on my own, but any help would be appreciated...

Comment: [This article on XML in iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) may be outdated, but is a good place to start. libxml2 is built into iOS - you can add it to your project and use it as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012030/adding-libxml2-in-xcode).