# Adding "${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2" to Header Search Paths breaks cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, dylib

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570295/1824282) solution to add libxml2.2.dylib to an old project I'm updating.

The imports look like

`#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>`

so I'm pretty sure I need to add `"${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2"` to Header Search Paths.

Trouble is when I do that I get a linker error because cocoapods blows up.

`ld: library not found for -lBolts`

When I set Header Search Paths back to default the pods work but the `HTMLParser.h` file is not found.

I tried changing the import to `#import <libxml2/libxml/HTMLParser.h>` but there's imports within the library using the `libxml` and I can't change them.

Any ideas how I can make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(inherited)` & `/usr/include/libxml2` to the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and
`-lxml2` into OTHER_LDFLAGS in the build settings.

```
#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks but when I do that I get the MACH-O linker error that it can't find my cocoapods.