# Headers for my static library not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries, header-files

I have a static library iOS project `ProjectCore`, that I want to include in the project `MyProject`.

In the library project I set:

```
PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = $(TARGET_NAME)
```

So I end up with the following structure

```
libProjectCore.a
ProjectCore (Folder)
+- ProjectCore.h
+- ProjectCoreUtil.h
```

In the directory `/.../DerivedData/MyProject-xyzabcd/Products/Release-iphoneos/`

Now I setup `MyProject`

- Add `ProjectCore` as a git submodule next to `MyProject.xcodeproj`
- Drag the `ProjectCore.xcodeproj` to Xcode
- Add the project as a dependency
- Link against `libProjectCore.a`
- I set it's "Header Search Path" to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` which should point to the folder above.

Curiously neither of the approaches work:

```
#import "ProjectCore.h" // With the (Recursive Flag set for the Headers)
#import <ProjectCore/ProjectCore.h> // The way RestKit does it
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/ProjectCore` in `User Header Search Paths` - it works for me.

Comment: Can you explain, why you're using "User Header Search Paths" instead of "Header Search Paths"?

Comment: Here's good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429031/header-search-paths-vs-user-header-search-paths-in-xcode

Comment: My problem was actually related to the fact, that the containing project had a configuration `preview` which was not present in the library project and therefore it did not find the headers, since their location is based on the configuration (`Release-iphoneos`).